# Oracle In-Memory does not show in v$im-segments

Tags: oracle12c

After enabling In-Memory in Database, I was trying to send a table to I-Memory by using `ALTER TABLE EMP INMEMORY;`

[image]

The Table was altered and then I had executed a simple query to check whether the table is actually altered. My query was as below;

```
SELECT ENAME, COUNT(*)
FROM EMP
WHERE ENAME='JAMES'
GROUP BY ENAME;
```

Query executed successfully, but when I execute  a statement on V$IM-SEGMENTS, no rows had been selected.

[image: I have attached the screen-shot]

If I'm not mistaken, When a table had moved to ORACLE IN-MEMORY, all segments should have been recorded with V$IM-SEGMENTS. If it is so why does my query does not showing in the v$im-segments?

Can someone help me out on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the default priority clause ["priority none"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/inmem/populating-objects-in-memory.html#GUID-DE12F0E2-8BEC-4326-A816-D812E54A3D12).

The documentation says:

> On-demand population
>
> By default, the INMEMORY PRIORITY parameter is set to NONE. In this
>   case, the database only populates the object when it is accessed
>   through a full table scan. If the object is never accessed, or if it
>   is accessed only through an index scan or fetch by rowid, then
>   population never occurs.

So, in your case you need to do full scan (select query covering all the rows in the table) to induce the population of table into inmemory segments. Following lists the altered steps:

```
Rem -- Enable table for inmemory
alter table emp inmemory;

Rem -- Perform full scan
select count(*) from emp;

Rem -- Sleep for few seconds
Rem -- This is to ensure segments are fully
Rem -- loaded into inmemory area before
Rem -- query v$im_segments
exec dbms_lock.sleep(30);

Rem -- Now query v$im_segments
select substr(segment_name,1,20), populate_status, bytes_not_populated from v$im_segments;
```